# SVG Images in HTML

Tags: html, image, svg

How to embed svg image in HTMl?

I'm doing `<img src = "path/to/my/file">`. It works well LOCALLY. But when I host it online in Heroku, the image does not shows up in Firefox, nor in Chrome.

Where I'm going wrong? Is there any debugging tools for this ?

Comment: how are you putting the file path or post your code

Comment: I'm using Django. `<img src="{% static "webapp/img/product_header.svg" %}" style="padding-left:30px";/>`

Comment: You need to provide actual code as received by browsers, as testable code, which means that you need to somehow identify the image data.

Comment: your path to image file must be complete . means src="http://www.abc.com/webapp/img.profuct_header.svg"

Comment: @RashFlash - I've provided similar type of path for other images as well (including both svg  and png files), ironically they work, but this one doesn't. any idea why?